# Why not implement deep copy in default copy constructor？

Tags: c++

All people keep remind us of the case when using default copy constructor and  default assign operator, be careful since they're shadow copy. However, I am always confused why not make deep copy by default among default copy constructor and default assign operator in c++, so that no one need to write their own copy constructor implementation in order to prevent any accident?

Comment: If you have container members (eg. `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::list`, etc), the default behaviour is deep copy. Just don't use raw pointers as members unless you want shallow copy.

Comment: If you have a member variable that is a pointer, how would the compiler know what it points to, and how large that memory is? If the compiler can't tell that, it can't do deep copying.

Comment: They're not "shadow copy". They just copy the members. That's it. If that doesn't suit your needs, you need to implement your own copy and assignment.

Comment: C++ doesn't have deep copy and shallow copy

Comment: @M.M Why say that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ implement copy by value, which means it basically does `x = y;`. In many cases this is enough.

However, in the case of pointers the compiler knows nothing about what is pointed to. It will copy the value of the pointer, but will not duplicate the underlying item because of this. For example, if you've got a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
  char *data;
};
```

Then what should the compiler do with `data`? It doesn't know if it points to a single `char` or an array of `char`. It doesn't know anything about how the memory was allocated or how it should be freed. It doesn't know if it should make a copy, or if all instances of `Foo` should point to the same instance.

Because of this the language takes a perfectly reasonable default stance, which is that only the value of the pointer will be copied. If you want anything more then you have to do it yourself as only you fully understand the use-case of the variable.

Comment: great explanation !